# ImageDataGenerator giving (almost) invisible images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am making a neural network architecture to predict whether an image is of a building, forest, glacier, mountain, sea or street. [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/puneet6060/intel-image-classification) to the dataset.

I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` to load and preprocess my data. The directory look like this:

[Dataset Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arZAy.png)

The directory contains images of size 150x150 like this:

[Photo from class 'Building'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gbJM.jpg)

### Code:

```
train_batch = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, color_mode='rgb')
test_batch = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=test_path)

>>> Found 14034 images belonging to 6 classes.
    Found 3000 images belonging to 6 classes.

img, labels = next(train_batch)
label_first_10 = labels[:10]
img_first_10 = img[:10]
class_name = ['buildings', 'forest', 'glacier', 'mountain', 'sea', 'street']

def plotImages(images_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip(images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

>>>
```

[Images after pre-processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkiR5.png)

As you can see the images our almost invisible and not even I can determine from which class it is! So, I am not sure model will be able to train on these type of images.
Can anyone has some other setting of hperparameters so my images will be visible and can be identified by human eye's.

Comment: Try `ax.imshow(img / 255.0)`

Comment: Thanks @Frightera, It worked! But how does it changed when divided by 255.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using floating point values in the argument of `imshow` it will assume that the range of the values is `[0,1]`, and any values outside of that range are clipped.

Therefore you should probably use `plt.imshow(img / 255)`.

If you instead use an integer type it will assume that the range is `[0,255]`, see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).